# Genetic Algorithm Not Improving

Tags: c#, algorithm, unity-game-engine

So what i've found is the tutorial i've been following and modifying doesn't improve itself. My population seems to keep hitting either a local minimum or it outright doesn't improve but the fitness keeps going up. I was wondering if anyone would be able to have a look, point me in a direction for more resources on genetic algorithms or on the project itself.

An overview of the project is to simply get the population to move around a map and find an object eventually i want to put this into a neural network so it can predict player movements.

Tutorial : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1oXr16Tdfvo
Project : https://wetransfer.com/downloads/16079695138c98a89d7e80aea8cfca2820190515023441/aa04d9

Fitness Calculation:

```
public float fitness
{
    get
    {

        float dist = Vector3.Distance(transform.position, target  );


          RaycastHit[] obstacles = Physics.RaycastAll(transform.position, target, obstacleLayer);
          float obstacleMultiplier = 1f - (0.15f * obstacles.Length);
        return (60 / (1 + dist)) * (hasCrashed ? 0.75f : 1f) * obstacleMultiplier;


    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not downloading your entire project, can you post the relevant parts of the code in your question?

Comment: Yeah thats understandable, heres the fitness calculation.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try [GeneticSharp](https://github.com/giacomelli/GeneticSharp).

I wrote some tutorials about it, and there is one specific how to use it with Unity3D:

- [Function optimization with GeneticSharp](http://diegogiacomelli.com.br/function-optimization-with-geneticsharp/)
- [TSP with GeneticSharp and Unity3D](http://diegogiacomelli.com.br/tsp-with-GeneticSharp-and-Unity3d/)
- [Starting an Unity3D project with GeneticSharp using dotnet new](http://diegogiacomelli.com.br/starting-an-unity3d-project-with-geneticsharp-using-dotnet-new/)